# Using Entity Framework on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ubuntu

I have successfully created a asp.net core mvc application that is hosted on a Ubuntu Linux server. The website runs and works properly.

Today I added Entity Framework to my project. I can post data to my database and retrieve it on my windows machine, so that is working.

When I move my project to my Ubuntu machine, the website works but when I try to access pages that require my database I get this error:

```
PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this Platform.
System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.LocalDB.GetLocalDBConnectionString(string localDbInstance)
```

Am I missing Entity Framework/SQL_Server packages on my Ubuntu machine or is there another cause?

Comment: You are going to use Linux, so use MySql or MariaDB which are native to those OS, it works with EF7 and .net Core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the error message:

> PlatformNotSupportedException: **LocalDB** is not supported on this Platform.

Which means, LocalDB is not supported on Linux.

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6336#issuecomment-240210699) on github:

> As @ErikEJ said, LocalDB is Windows only. On Linux, you can use EF Core with a remote SQL Server (running on Windows), the preview version of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-overview, or [SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database). Alternatively, you can use the Postgres and SQLite providers.

So in summary, you need another database.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use the local DB file from visual studio on Ubuntu its  not supported as error say , but you can use the sql server 2017 as DataBase Engine its now supporting linux  or any supported DBMS on Ubuntu

you can use this link to install sql server 2017 in linux 
[Installation guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup)

Comment: this would be a great solution, however sql server 2017 requires 3.5gb RAM in order to install. Unfortunately, I don't have that much ram.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by using SQLite and creating a local .db file. see http://jeninja.net/Links for some helpful resources.